# Location Manager - requestLocationUpdates crashes

Tags: android, multithreading, gps, geolocation

I am trying to fetch current user location - city, using the code below :

```
private String getCurrentLocation() {

        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
try {
            gps_enabled = locManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = locManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

   if(!gps_enabled){
      // Show alert dialog
    }

   if (gps_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    1000, 1, locListener,Looper.getMainLooper());
        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            location = locManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (network_enabled && location == null) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locListener,Looper.getMainLooper());
        }

        if (network_enabled && location == null) {
            location = locManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

  Fetch city code...
...

}
```

Since this takes bit time to load i am using async task to show loader when the activity starts up.

```
private class GetLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getCurrentLocation();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            onFinshGetLocationTask(result);
        }
    }
```

It was crashing, so i have used looper when we requestLocationUpdates

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locListener,Looper.getMainLooper());
```

But still app crashes saying  "Only one Looper may be created per thread"

I have looked into many threads but still unable to solve it.

Comment: @Selvin I am calling looper in doInBackground method, how can i correct my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you dont need to do this in Asynctask. Simply call it without using thread. It will create its own thread.

And try using it without looper.

Use this method

```
requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

And call getCurrentLocation(); without using asynctask.

And in doInBackGround of Asynctask

```
@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
         Looper.prepare();
         //do your task
         Looper.myLooper().quit();

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show me how ? because all my code is in the method, also as its processing is slow i need to show loader

Comment: Edited answer. Please check.

Comment: I tried your solution, it crashes saying "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()", i have used async task as i need to show loader

Comment: If i dont use async task it works fine, since i am callling this in onCreate() it will take bit time to load, so i want to show loader to the user indicating something is happening

Comment: I already said that, you dont have to use asynctask. any kind of location update will take time. And for your error of looper . see my edited answer

Comment: thanks, how can i intimate the user that its talking some time to load ?

Comment: you can use a progressbar for first time.
or you can just simply show toast like 
This may take a while....

Comment: How can i show a alert dialog without using Async task ? can you pleas guide me?, as i moving from A - > B and B is where my geolocation code is in onCreate()

Comment: Display the progress bar before you call the method, and dismiss after method is done. and apply synchronized keyword to method